# Android Widget Error inflating class android.widget.EditText

Tags: java, android, widget

I have a problem about my EditText... Here is my class for the widget :

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EurToFt extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static final double TAUX_DE_CHANGE = 377.81;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // Parcourir tous les widgets créés pour cet ID de widget
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            // Récupérer les vues du widget
            @SuppressLint("RemoteViewLayout") RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.eur_to_ft);

            EditText euroEditText = views.apply(context, null).findViewById(R.id.val_eur);
            TextView forintTextView = views.apply(context, null).findViewById(R.id.val_forint);

            // Ajouter un TextWatcher à l'EditText pour mettre à jour le TextView
            euroEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    // Rien à faire ici
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // Convertir la valeur en euros en forints et mettre à jour le TextView
                    String euroString = euroEditText.getText().toString();
                    if (!euroString.isEmpty()) {
                        double euroValue = Double.parseDouble(euroString);
                        double forintValue = euroValue * TAUX_DE_CHANGE;
                        forintTextView.setText(String.format("%.2f", forintValue));
                    } else {
                        forintTextView.setText("");
                    }

                    // Mettre à jour le widget
                    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // Rien à faire ici
                }
            });

            // Mettre à jour le widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

My XML file just contains an EditText and Textview.
I also have eur_to_ft_info.xml which was generated by android studio when I created the widget and my manifest was also completed with :

```
<receiver
            android:name=".EurToFt"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/eur_to_ft_info" />
        </receiver>
```

When I run the project, I don't have an error but if I try to create a widget I got this error :

```
    Process: com.example.eurtoforint, PID: 21213
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.eurtoforint.EurToFt: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.eurtoforint:layout/eur_to_ft: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.eurtoforint:layout/eur_to_ft: Error inflating class android.widget.EditText
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4890)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleReceiver(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2417)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.eurtoforint:layout/eur_to_ft: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.eurtoforint:layout/eur_to_ft: Error inflating class android.widget.EditText
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.eurtoforint:layout/eur_to_ft: Error inflating class android.widget.EditText
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.eurtoforint:layout/eur_to_ft: Class not allowed to be inflated android.widget.EditText
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.failNotAllowed(LayoutInflater.java:919)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:843)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:952)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:972)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1026)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:983)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1145)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1106)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:692)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:544)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.inflateView(RemoteViews.java:5924)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.inflateView(RemoteViews.java:5893)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:5850)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:5842)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:5837)
        at com.example.eurtoforint.EurToFt.onUpdate(EurToFt.java:24)
        at android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider.onReceive(AppWidgetProvider.java:66)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4881)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleReceiver(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2417)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

Can someone able to correct me ? Thank you !